# Generate a list with a foreach loop that uses a common field as a heading

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm building a website in the ASP.NET framework and I'm trying to dynamically create list of job listings based on the state like so:

```
**Utah**

Accounting Clerk - HDQ

Cattle Manager - EVA

Payroll Specialist - HDQ

Real Estate Transactions Assistant - HDQ

Senior Accountant - HDQ

Senior Accountant - DLL

Senior IT Manager - EVA

**Washington**

Ag Tech - AGNW

Grain Facility Operator - AGNW
```

What I have currently makes a new state heading for every entry, but what I want is for every listing to be under a single state:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h2 id="@item.State">@item.State</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>@item.JobTitle - @item.Location</li>
    </ul>
}
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but as I'm pretty new at this, I'm not sure how it's done.

Comment: create a global variable for state outside your loop and inside your loop just check if that variable is not equal to @item.state then set the variable and create the <h2> tag. this is if you want to use the for loop.

Comment: See GroupBy in linq https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group` your model data by State like this:-

```
@foreach (var state in Model.GroupBy(x => x.State))
{
    <h2 id="@state.Key">@state.Key</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach(var details in state)
        {
             <li>@details.JobTitle - @details.Location</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

But, I would suggest you to do this grouping logic in you controller and pass details to View and simply iterate over it and display the data rather than writing grouping logic in View.

Order By States:-

```
Model.GroupBy(x => x.State).OrderBy(x => x.Key)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the <h2> under item where it's not available in the current context. How do I resolve that?

Comment: @droo46 - Oops! My bad used default variable name corrected. Please check.

Comment: Looks and works great. Is there a way to put the groups in alphabetical order?

Comment: @droo46 - Absolutely, Please check my update, you need to simply use `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 0):

You must group by state like this:

```
@foreach (var state in Model.Select(x => x.State).GroupBy(x => x))
{
   <h2 id="@state">@state</h2>
   <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.State == state))
        {

                <li>@item.JobTitle - @item.Location</li>

        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm after, but I'm getting an error on the line with the <h2> where item isn't available in the context as well as an error on x.State == state that says that the operator can't be applied. How would I go about resolving those errors?